# Jenkins HelloWorldBuilder not shown in Console

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I have done the plugin tutorial from the jenkins wiki: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial.

I have followed the instructions and built it and installed it in Jenkins. I can see the "French" checkbox in the configure menu but I do not get the "Hello name" console output when building projects. I could not find any information about that in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Had to add "Say hello world" as a pre-build step.